# Option pricing under Vasicek, CIR, H-L and BDT model

Tags: options, option-pricing, fixed-income, interest-rates, stochastic-processes

I have implemented and calibrated recombining trees on Excel for the Vasicek, the Cox-Ingersoll-Ross, the Ho-Lee and the Black-Derman-Toy model. I now would like to price some options with these models and see how close they are to reality, for curiosity.

However, I cannot think of any easy suitable option. I thought about Asian options given that some of them are directly related to the level interest rates, but it seems complicated in the end. Would you have some ideas ?

Thanks for your help,

KB

Comment: Have you tried Caplets or Swaptions? Caplets should be really easy. Because underlying rate in caplet is longer than the rate you are modelling you can approximate underlying rate  say Libor USD 3M as instantaneous risk free rate r*(1+a), where "a" is derived from current yield curve between ON rate and 3M rate.